# DXA 2.0 Caching not working as expected

Tags: dxa, web8.5, cache, dxa-2.0

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and DXA 2.0, after publishing content to live website we feel that content takes a long time to appear and sometimes it appears only after restarting the Content Service and Tomcat service. We have enabled all levels of caching and Tridion object caching using Apache ActiveMQ. We are using Linux server at Content Delivery side.

Comment: Can you please provide some additional data, for example how long does it take for something to appear, can you measure it? That will help you in identifying what cache is the culprit. Usually with caching related issues, most of the time it turns out that the Cache Channel Service is not correctly configured or is malfunctioning. Can you confirm that it's working as expected?

Comment: Your title states that caching is not working as expected,so can you perhaps **edit** your question and add what cache settings you have in your DXA setup and indicate your expectation of those settings exactly?

Answer (score 2):

> sometimes it appears only after restarting the Content Service and Tomcat service.

You may want to test this independently, so you can figure out *which* cache is holding your content updates hostage (as the solution is different depending on which).

You can test content updates on the Content Service by querying the service directly - check logs in debug to find examples of a query for a given page, then update content on that page, then try to retrieve it using the web service (or create a simple app that doesn't have DXA-level caching in it to get the content).

- If you don't see the content update, then your Content Service Cache *invalidation* is not working correctly. I would recommend reading [this article](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/feed/posts/how-to-connect-sdl-web-8-content-interaction-service-cis-with-activemq) by Velu on how to set this up properly.
- If you see the content update, then you know Content Service Caching is fine, and you can focus on DXA caching.

DXA has various types of caching levels, and they're all time based. You will have to discuss and agree with your business owners on what is an acceptable time to cache. On a busy site even a 30 second cache will make a huge difference, so don't be afraid to play around with this. In my experience, anything between 5 and 15 minutes is acceptable by the business, and this really depends on how often time-sensitive content updates are done.

I hope the above helps getting started on the wonderful journey of cache tuning.

Comment: so are you saying that DXA's caches are not invalidated when contents are updated (published/unpublished)? There is no invalidation mechanism built into DXA's caching?

Comment: DXA caches are time based, yes.

Comment: is there any plan to implement some kind of cache invalidation in DXA caches?

Comment: That’s a question for @bart Koopman